# Present a modal view controller in landscape when the iphone turn to landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iPhone app which works all the time works in portrait.

This app has a navigation view controller and the `rootViewcontroller` which is shown in portrait too. I'd like present a `viewController` when the iPhone is turned to landscape and dismiss this view controller when the app is turned back to portrait.

Currently I have achieved this but my views are totally moved:

Step1:
[image: Step1]

Step2:

[image: Step2]

Step3:
[image: Step3]

I tried several things, but I don't know if I'm choosing the right way:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return YES;
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{


 }

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] ==    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        UIStoryboard *currentStoryboar = [self storyboard];
        ASTBigProgressViewController *bigProgress = [currentStoryboar instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ASTBigProgressViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:bigProgress animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
            UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight |     UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

I'd like that when the view controller is turned, it doesn't turn the view keeping it in the same position. I tried:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return NO;
}
```

But obviously the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method is not called.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple docs on [Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm working in this, and it's working more and less well. Just I have the problem that the landscape modal view appears from the right of the view instead from the bottom.

Comment: Finally, I've used this way and I fixed the problem with the animation from the right using a modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

Answer (score 0):

Do not present or dismiss a view controller during the rotation process, this is within viewWillRotateRotat and viewDidRotate... and shouldViewRotate etc.

You could use performSelector:withDelay. Even a short Delay of 0.0 or 0.01 should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think, it's a good answer but too trick, isn't? I mean, to depend of a delay is not very accurate.

Comment: Right. First of all the brief delay would certainly detach the rotating process from your present and dismiss but it is not quite accurate. You may want to add some research and look for a good method to hook in. However, you may still need to detach it with a delay of 0.